# How to convert inkscape arrow to single path?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I need to use scripted SVG in my web page. I made the basic things in Inkscape.

I have two arrows, like this:

[image]

They should change colors using Javascript which I wrote. However arrow markers are not bound to arrows in any way, which is a complication.

I'd like to convert the arrow to single `<path>` object, which would be much easier to manipulate using scripts. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the line with the arrow head, click Path > Stroke to Path, Object > Ungroup. Remove the stroke from the arrow head. You will have to move the arrow head afterwards as it will overlap the line.  Then select both, and click Path > Unite.

The result is a single object, made from one path.

[image]

Note: once you do this, the line becomes baked as a shape, and will no longer have the same behaviour as a line with an arrow head.